# Automate MySQL in phpMyAdmin

Tags: php, mysql

I have a mysql database with three tables:

1. a list of users
2. a list of tasks
3. a table to say which users will do which task (join table)

Each day the list of tasks will change. So I will manually change this task list in phpmyadmin. What I want is for every task to be assigned to every user. I can see that this is manually possible in phpmyadmin but it would not really be feasible to do this manually for more than a few users.

Is there a quick piece of sql or something that can accomplish this? Or will I have to do a php script?

So far I just have some pseudo code that I thought about, wanted to make sure that this is the best approach before I commit myself:

```
Get current number of users
Get current number of tasks

From user 1 to the last user
     From task 1 to the last task
         assign current task in loop to current user in loop
```

Comment: Use the MySQL Event Scheduler to run a query every day.

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/event-scheduler.html

Comment: It's not clear what your question is really about. Do you need to know how to write the query that does the assignment, or do you need to know how to run the query every day automatically?

Comment: I'm really asking to see if there is a query that will do this automatically